# Particles in XNA - can't get em to work

Tags: xna, particles

I am trying to have an explosion appear when a player lands on a mine. I checked out the particle example on the XNA website but it seemed to over complicate it a lot. So any simpler neater explosion particle effect would be cool to be linked to ;)

But on to the problem, i can't even see the explosion though i cannot see what is going wrong. Here's my explosion class (a lot of this is from the particle example):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PackedVector;

namespace StayUp
{


struct ExplosionVertex
    {
        public Vector3 Position;
        public Short2 Corner;
        public Color Random;
        public float Time;
        public Vector3 Velocity;

        public ExplosionVertex(Vector3 position, Short2 Corner, Vector3 velocity, Color random, float Time)
        {
            this.Position = position;
            this.Corner = Corner;
            this.Velocity = velocity;
            this.Random = random;
            this.Time = Time;
        }

        public static readonly VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
        (
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Short2,
                                VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),

            new VertexElement(4, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                                VertexElementUsage.Position, 1),

            new VertexElement(16, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                                    VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),

            new VertexElement(28, VertexElementFormat.Color,
                                    VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),

            new VertexElement(32, VertexElementFormat.Single,
                                    VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
        );


        // Describe the size of this vertex structure.
        public const int SizeInBytes = 36;
    }

    public class Explosion : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        #region Fields

        string TextureName = "explosion";
        int MaxParticles = 100;
        TimeSpan Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        float DurationRandomness = 1;
        float MinHorizontalVelocity = 0.02f;
        float MaxHorizontalVelocity = 0.03f;
        float MinVerticalVelocity = -0.02f;
        float MaxVerticalVelocity = 0.02f;
        float EndVelocity = 0;
        Color MinColor = Color.DarkGray;
        Color MaxColor = Color.Gray;
        float MinRotateSpeed = -1;
        float MaxRotateSpeed = 1;
        float MinStartSize = 0.07f;
        float MaxStartSize = 0.07f;
        float MinEndSize = 0.7f;
        float MaxEndSize = 1.4f;
        BlendState blendState = BlendState.Additive;


        // For loading the effect and particle texture.
        ContentManager content;


        // Custom effect for drawing particles. This computes the particle
        // animation entirely in the vertex shader: no per-particle CPU work required!
        Effect particleEffect;


        // Shortcuts for accessing frequently changed effect parameters.
        EffectParameter effectViewParameter;
        EffectParameter effectProjectionParameter;
        EffectParameter effectViewportScaleParameter;
        EffectParameter effectTimeParameter;


        // An array of particles, treated as a circular queue.
        ExplosionVertex[] particles;

        // A vertex buffer holding our particles. This contains the same data as
        // the particles array, but copied across to where the GPU can access it.
        DynamicVertexBuffer vertexBuffer;


        // Index buffer turns sets of four vertices into particle quads (pairs of triangles).
        IndexBuffer indexBuffer;



        int firstActiveParticle;
        int firstNewParticle;
        int firstFreeParticle;
        int firstRetiredParticle;


        // Store the current time, in seconds.
        float currentTime;


        // Count how many times Draw has been called. This is used to know
        // when it is safe to retire old particles back into the free list.
        int drawCounter;


        // Shared random number generator.
        static Random random = new Random();


        #endregion

        #region Initialization


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public Explosion(Game game, ContentManager content)
            : base(game)
        {
            this.content = content;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the component.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            // Allocate the particle array, and fill in the Corner fields (which never change).
            particles = new ExplosionVertex[MaxParticles * 4];

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxParticles; i++)
            {
                particles[i * 4 + 0].Corner = new Short2(-1, -1);
                particles[i * 4 + 1].Corner = new Short2(1, -1);
                particles[i * 4 + 2].Corner = new Short2(1, 1);
                particles[i * 4 + 3].Corner = new Short2(-1, 1);
            }

            base.Initialize();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Loads graphics for the particle system.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            LoadParticleEffect();

            // Create a dynamic vertex buffer.
            vertexBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, ExplosionVertex.VertexDeclaration,
                                                   MaxParticles * 4, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

            // Create and populate the index buffer.
            ushort[] indices = new ushort[MaxParticles * 6];

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxParticles; i++)
            {
                indices[i * 6 + 0] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 0);
                indices[i * 6 + 1] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 1);
                indices[i * 6 + 2] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 2);

                indices[i * 6 + 3] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 0);
                indices[i * 6 + 4] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 2);
                indices[i * 6 + 5] = (ushort)(i * 4 + 3);
            }

            indexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(ushort), indices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

            indexBuffer.SetData(indices);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for loading and initializing the particle effect.
        /// </summary>
        void LoadParticleEffect()
        {
            Effect effect = content.Load<Effect>("ParticleEffect");

            // If we have several particle systems, the content manager will return
            // a single shared effect instance to them all. But we want to preconfigure
            // the effect with parameters that are specific to this particular
            // particle system. By cloning the effect, we prevent one particle system
            // from stomping over the parameter settings of another.

            particleEffect = effect.Clone();

            EffectParameterCollection parameters = particleEffect.Parameters;

            // Look up shortcuts for parameters that change every frame.
            effectViewParameter = parameters["View"];
            effectProjectionParameter = parameters["Projection"];
            effectViewportScaleParameter = parameters["ViewportScale"];
            effectTimeParameter = parameters["CurrentTime"];

            // Set the values of parameters that do not change.
            parameters["Duration"].SetValue((float)Duration.TotalSeconds);
            parameters["DurationRandomness"].SetValue(DurationRandomness);
            parameters["Gravity"].SetValue(Vector3.Zero);
            parameters["EndVelocity"].SetValue(EndVelocity);
            parameters["MinColor"].SetValue(MinColor.ToVector4());
            parameters["MaxColor"].SetValue(MaxColor.ToVector4());

            parameters["RotateSpeed"].SetValue(
                new Vector2(MinRotateSpeed, MaxRotateSpeed));

            parameters["StartSize"].SetValue(
                new Vector2(MinStartSize, MaxStartSize));

            parameters["EndSize"].SetValue(
                new Vector2(MinEndSize, MaxEndSize));

            // Load the particle texture, and set it onto the effect.
            Texture2D texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(TextureName);

            parameters["Tex"].SetValue(texture);
        }


        #endregion

        #region Update and Draw


        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the particle system.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (gameTime == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("gameTime");

            currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            RetireActiveParticles();
            FreeRetiredParticles();

            // If we let our timer go on increasing for ever, it would eventually
            // run out of floating point precision, at which point the particles
            // would render incorrectly. An easy way to prevent this is to notice
            // that the time value doesn't matter when no particles are being drawn,
            // so we can reset it back to zero any time the active queue is empty.

            if (firstActiveParticle == firstFreeParticle)
                currentTime = 0;

            if (firstRetiredParticle == firstActiveParticle)
                drawCounter = 0;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for checking when active particles have reached the end of
        /// their life. It moves old particles from the active area of the queue
        /// to the retired section.
        /// </summary>
        void RetireActiveParticles()
        {
            float particleDuration = (float)Duration.TotalSeconds;

            while (firstActiveParticle != firstNewParticle)
            {
                // Is this particle old enough to retire?
                // We multiply the active particle index by four, because each
                // particle consists of a quad that is made up of four vertices.
                float particleAge = currentTime - particles[firstActiveParticle * 4].Time;

                if (particleAge < particleDuration)
                    break;

                // Remember the time at which we retired this particle.
                particles[firstActiveParticle * 4].Time = drawCounter;

                // Move the particle from the active to the retired queue.
                firstActiveParticle++;

                if (firstActiveParticle >= MaxParticles)
                    firstActiveParticle = 0;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for checking when retired particles have been kept around long
        /// enough that we can be sure the GPU is no longer using them. It moves
        /// old particles from the retired area of the queue to the free section.
        /// </summary>
        void FreeRetiredParticles()
        {
            while (firstRetiredParticle != firstActiveParticle)
            {
                // Has this particle been unused long enough that
                // the GPU is sure to be finished with it?
                // We multiply the retired particle index by four, because each
                // particle consists of a quad that is made up of four vertices.
                int age = drawCounter - (int)particles[firstRetiredParticle * 4].Time;

                // The GPU is never supposed to get more than 2 frames behind the CPU.
                // We add 1 to that, just to be safe in case of buggy drivers that
                // might bend the rules and let the GPU get further behind.
                if (age < 3)
                    break;

                // Move the particle from the retired to the free queue.
                firstRetiredParticle++;

                if (firstRetiredParticle >= MaxParticles)
                    firstRetiredParticle = 0;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the particle system.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsDevice;

            // Restore the vertex buffer contents if the graphics device was lost.
            if (vertexBuffer.IsContentLost)
            {
                vertexBuffer.SetData(particles);
            }

            // If there are any particles waiting in the newly added queue,
            // we'd better upload them to the GPU ready for drawing.
            if (firstNewParticle != firstFreeParticle)
            {
                AddNewParticlesToVertexBuffer();
            }

            // If there are any active particles, draw them now!
            if (firstActiveParticle != firstFreeParticle)
            {
                device.BlendState = blendState;
                device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;

                effectViewportScaleParameter.SetValue(new Vector2(0.5f / device.Viewport.AspectRatio, -0.5f));

                effectTimeParameter.SetValue(currentTime);

                device.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
                device.Indices = indexBuffer;


                foreach (EffectPass pass in particleEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                {
                    pass.Apply();

                    if (firstActiveParticle < firstFreeParticle)
                    {
                        device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0,
                                                     firstActiveParticle * 4, (firstFreeParticle - firstActiveParticle) * 4,
                                                     firstActiveParticle * 6, (firstFreeParticle - firstActiveParticle) * 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0,
                                                     firstActiveParticle * 4, (MaxParticles - firstActiveParticle) * 4,
                                                     firstActiveParticle * 6, (MaxParticles - firstActiveParticle) * 2);

                        if (firstFreeParticle > 0)
                        {
                            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0,
                                                         0, firstFreeParticle * 4,
                                                         0, firstFreeParticle * 2);
                        }
                    }
                }

                device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
            }

            drawCounter++;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for uploading new particles from our managed
        /// array to the GPU vertex buffer.
        /// </summary>
        void AddNewParticlesToVertexBuffer()
        {
            int stride = ExplosionVertex.SizeInBytes;

            if (firstNewParticle < firstFreeParticle)
            {
                // If the new particles are all in one consecutive range,
                // we can upload them all in a single call.
                vertexBuffer.SetData(firstNewParticle * stride * 4, particles,
                                     firstNewParticle * 4,
                                     (firstFreeParticle - firstNewParticle) * 4,
                                     stride, SetDataOptions.NoOverwrite);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the new particle range wraps past the end of the queue
                // back to the start, we must split them over two upload calls.
                vertexBuffer.SetData(firstNewParticle * stride * 4, particles,
                                     firstNewParticle * 4,
                                     (MaxParticles - firstNewParticle) * 4,
                                     stride, SetDataOptions.NoOverwrite);

                if (firstFreeParticle > 0)
                {
                    vertexBuffer.SetData(0, particles,
                                         0, firstFreeParticle * 4,
                                         stride, SetDataOptions.NoOverwrite);
                }
            }

            // Move the particles we just uploaded from the new to the active queue.
            firstNewParticle = firstFreeParticle;
        }


        #endregion

        #region Public Methods


        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the camera view and projection matrices
        /// that will be used to draw this particle system.
        /// </summary>
        public void SetCamera(Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            effectViewParameter.SetValue(view);
            effectProjectionParameter.SetValue(projection);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a new particle to the system.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddParticle(Vector3 position, Vector3 velocity)
        {
            // Figure out where in the circular queue to allocate the new particle.
            int nextFreeParticle = firstFreeParticle + 1;

            if (nextFreeParticle >= MaxParticles)
                nextFreeParticle = 0;

            // If there are no free particles, we just have to give up.
            if (nextFreeParticle == firstRetiredParticle)
                return;

            // Add in some random amount of horizontal velocity.
            float horizontalVelocity = MathHelper.Lerp(MinHorizontalVelocity,
                                                       MaxHorizontalVelocity,
                                                       (float)random.NextDouble());

            double horizontalAngle = random.NextDouble() * MathHelper.TwoPi;

            velocity.X += horizontalVelocity * (float)Math.Cos(horizontalAngle);
            velocity.Z += horizontalVelocity * (float)Math.Sin(horizontalAngle);

            // Add in some random amount of vertical velocity.
            velocity.Y += MathHelper.Lerp(MinVerticalVelocity,
                                          MaxVerticalVelocity,
                                          (float)random.NextDouble());

            // Choose four random control values. These will be used by the vertex
            // shader to give each particle a different size, rotation, and color.
            Color randomValues = new Color((byte)random.Next(255),
                                           (byte)random.Next(255),
                                           (byte)random.Next(255),
                                           (byte)random.Next(255));

            // Fill in the particle vertex structure.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                particles[firstFreeParticle * 4 + i].Position = position;
                particles[firstFreeParticle * 4 + i].Velocity = velocity;
                particles[firstFreeParticle * 4 + i].Random = randomValues;
                particles[firstFreeParticle * 4 + i].Time = currentTime;
            }

            firstFreeParticle = nextFreeParticle;
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here is my HLSL (also HLSL from example)

```
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
float2 ViewportScale;


float CurrentTime;


float Duration;
float DurationRandomness;
float3 Gravity;
float EndVelocity;
float4 MinColor;
float4 MaxColor;


float2 RotateSpeed;
float2 StartSize;
float2 EndSize;


texture Tex;

sampler TexSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Tex>;

    MinFilter = Linear;
    MagFilter = Linear;
    MipFilter = Linear;

    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float2 Corner : POSITION0;
    float3 Position : POSITION1;
    float3 Velocity : NORMAL0;
    float4 Random : COLOR0;
    float Time : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : COLOR1;
};

float4 ComputeParticlePosition(float3 position, float3 velocity, float age, float normalizedAge)
{
    float startVelocity = length(velocity);

    float endVelocity = startVelocity * EndVelocity;

    float velocityIntegral = startVelocity * normalizedAge +
                             (endVelocity - startVelocity) * normalizedAge *
                                                             normalizedAge / 2;

    position += normalize(velocity) * velocityIntegral * Duration;

    position += Gravity * age * normalizedAge;

    return mul(mul(float4(position, 1), View), Projection);
}


float ComputeParticleSize(float randomValue, float normalizedAge)
{
    float startSize = lerp(StartSize.x, StartSize.y, randomValue);
    float endSize = lerp(EndSize.x, EndSize.y, randomValue);

    float size = lerp(startSize, endSize, normalizedAge);

    return size * Projection._m11;
}


float4 ComputeParticleColor(float4 projectedPosition, float randomValue, float normalizedAge)
{
    float4 color = lerp(MinColor, MaxColor, randomValue);

    color.a *= normalizedAge * (1-normalizedAge) * (1-normalizedAge) * 6.7;

    return color;
}


float2x2 ComputeParticleRotation(float randomValue, float age)
{    
    // Apply a random factor to make each particle rotate at a different speed.
    float rotateSpeed = lerp(RotateSpeed.x, RotateSpeed.y, randomValue);

    float rotation = rotateSpeed * age;

    // Compute a 2x2 rotation matrix.
    float c = cos(rotation);
    float s = sin(rotation);

    return float2x2(c, -s, s, c);
}


VertexShaderOutput ParticleVertexShader(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float age = CurrentTime - input.Time;

    age *= 1 + input.Random.x * DurationRandomness;

    float normalizedAge = saturate(age / Duration);

    output.Position = ComputeParticlePosition(input.Position, input.Velocity, age, normalizedAge);

    float size = ComputeParticleSize(input.Random.y, normalizedAge);
    float2x2 rotation = ComputeParticleRotation(input.Random.w, age);

    output.Position.xy += mul(input.Corner, rotation) * size * ViewportScale;

    output.Color = ComputeParticleColor(output.Position, input.Random.z, normalizedAge);
    output.TextureCoordinate = (input.Corner + 1) / 2;

    return output;
}


float4 ParticlePixelShader(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 output = tex2D(TexSampler, input.TextureCoordinate) * input.Color;
    return output;
}


technique Particles
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 ParticleVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 ParticlePixelShader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the Mercury Particle Engine if you don't want to code your own http://mpe.codeplex.com/. Probably not simpler but a lot neater.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention, looking for 3D, not 2D :P

Comment: Also, i tried billboarding with MPE, but the problem is it renders all explosions on one flat image. I need them on staggered levels, not all one flat plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the example on the site. Realized i was using it wrong and should have used it more like a library.

Answer (score -1):

The first element on your struct ExplosionVertex is position, so the first element in your VertexDeclaration has to be VertexElementFormat.Vector3

Your VertexDeclaration has to describe your particle struct, and the order is very important

```
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Short2 Corner;
    public Color Random;
    public float Time;
    public Vector3 Velocity;

    public static readonly VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
    (
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                            VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),

        new VertexElement(11, VertexElementFormat.Short2,
                            VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),

        new VertexElement(15, VertexElementFormat.Color,
                                VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),

        new VertexElement(19, VertexElementFormat.Single,
                                VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1),

        new VertexElement(23, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                                VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 2)
    );

    public const int SizeInBytes = 36;
```

Comment: Tried and didn't work, also Position0 goes the corner, not to the position, so it is correct how it currently is.

Comment: your struct field order is Vector3, short2, Color, float and Vector3, and your declaration order is short2, Vector3, Vector3, Color, Single,   that is wrong say what you say.